# Combine - assigning class published properties to a property in a data model struct

Tags: swift, combine

I'm getting an error - `Key path value type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo, [Bar]?>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'WriteableKeyPath<Foo, [Bar]?>'` - trying to publish something from a repository class into an instance of my main data model struct, and not sure what to do with this error.

### The Situation

I have a "Foo" which can have an array of "Bars" loaded in it, and they are loaded in separate repositories as separate collections in my database.

I have a `FooViewModel` which looks at one foo as a published property, and then I inject a `barRepository` into that ViewModel to load all the bars tied to that foo when the user presses a button.

My viewModel has a `subscribeToBarActions()` that gets called when the user presses this button, and this function attempts to subscribe to a `barsPublisher` variable within the repository, and to assign them to a `bars` property within the foo object in the ViewModel.

### My Code

This method in the ViewModel is called when the user clicks on the "Load Bars" button in the Foo (the error is happening at the `.assign(...)` line). My goal here is to subscribe to the bar array, and map them to the bars property in the foo object in the ViewModel:

```
    func subscribeToFooBars() {
        self.fooBarRepository.barPublisher
            .map { bars in
                .map { bar in
                    Bar.self
                }
            }
            .assign(to: \.bars, on: self.foo)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        self.fooBarRepository.loadData()
    }
```

Here is the Foo structure that has bars as a variable within it - when we initially load instances of Foo, bars is instantiated either as nil or as an empty array (I don't have a strong reason for doing one vs. the other right now).

```
struct Foo: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    // Identifiers
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var description: String?
    var bars: [Bar]?
```

And my `fooBarRepository` just has this publisher that is supposed to load and store the bars that are published to the ViewModel, intended to save them to the bar property

```
class BarRepository: ObservableObject, BarStoreType {
    
    @Published var bars = [Bar]()
    var barsPublished: Published<[Bar]> { _bars }
    var barsPublisher: Published<[Bar]>.Publisher { $bars }
```

My `foo` property within the ViewModel is published, but the `bars` property inside that structure is not published. I'm wondering if that might be the issue, or if it might have to do with the fact that the repository is a reference type while the Foo struct is a value type. Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Researching this a little more, it looks like this is definitely because the  Bar property in my data model is in a struct, where the Bar property in my repository is in a class.

See this [Swift by Sundell article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift/) for more info.

So to get around this, I realize I don't actually need the Bars array to be contained inside my Foo (that probably makes it easier if it's not, because I don't want that data saving to the instance of Foo in my database). I just need to make sure they're in the same ViewModel.

So I added `@Published var bars: [Bar]?` to my ViewModel, and now I have the subscription in my repository assign itself directly to that variable in the ViewModel. I don't need them to be actually linked under the same data model instance of `Foo`, as long as they're in the same `FooCellViewModel`.

```
    func subscribeToFooBars() {
        self.fooBarRepository.BarPublisher
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .assign(to: \.bars, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```